# Why does Python sometimes throw ValueErrors in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, subprocess

I have some Python 3.5 code that looks approximately like this:

```
try:
    my_process = Popen(someargs, stdin=None, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = my_process.communicate(timeout=10)
    my_process.wait()
except TimeoutExpired:
    my_process.kill()
    stdout, stderr = my_process.communicate()
```

I am trying to follow the principle described in [the python subprocess documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate), namely that in the case of a TimeoutError, I should kill the process manually, then complete the communication.

In principle that sounds fine, but periodically (maybe every 1 in 50 times, very approximately), I get an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xyz/myprogram/myprogram", line 125, in <module>
    stdout, stderr = my_process.communicate()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1068, in communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1689, in _communicate
    selector.register(self.stdout, selectors.EVENT_READ)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/selectors.py", line 342, in register
    key = super().register(fileobj, events, data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/selectors.py", line 228, in register
    key = SelectorKey(fileobj, self._fileobj_lookup(fileobj), events, data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/selectors.py", line 215, in _fileobj_lookup
    return _fileobj_to_fd(fileobj)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/selectors.py", line 39, in _fileobj_to_fd
    "{!r}".format(fileobj)) from None
ValueError: Invalid file object: <_io.BufferedReader name=5>
```

Line 125 is the second `communicate()` line in my case.

It would appear that this is failing because some stream underlying the process object has closed or terminated - perhaps sometimes by chance this happens between the `kill()` and the `communicate()`?. But if so, is there a graceful way I should be handling this? The Python docs don't appear to cover this case.

Comment: are you using multiple threads? Otherwise, it looks like a bug. Could you create a dummy `child.py` to pass in `someargs`, to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Here's the code to reproduce this issue in 3.6.0:

`    import subprocess
    import time
    
    po = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/ls'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    time.sleep(1)
    out, err = po.communicate(timeout=1)
    out, err = po.communicate(timeout=1)`

Answer (score 2):

To workaround `my_process.communicate()` raising `ValueError` in the exception handler, you could read from the streams directly (simpler code path -- don't use it in the general case):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, TimeoutExpired

with Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE) as process:
    try:
        stdout, stderr = process.communicate(timeout=10)
    except TimeoutExpired:
        process.kill()
        stdout = process.stdout.read() # the process is dead, no deadlock
        stderr = process.stderr.read()
```

On Python 3.5, you could use `subprocess.run()`:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE, TimeoutExpired

try:
    result = subprocess.run(cmd, timeout=10, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
except TimeoutExpired as e:
    result = e
stdout, stderr = result.stdout, result.stderr
```

Though it handles `TimeoutExpired` the same way as your code and therefore you can get `ValueError` anyway. If you get `ValueError` with this code; report the issue at http://bugs.python.org

Comment: Very interesting. Did not know about the improvements in Python 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

### Improved Answer

Using an empty bytes object as return values for `stdout` and `stderr` could be a solution. `my_process.communicate()` reads the pipes for you. So better not to use a file objects here:

```
try:
    my_process = Popen(someargs, stdin=None, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = my_process.communicate(timeout=10)
    my_process.wait()
except TimeoutExpired:
    my_process.kill()
    try:
        stdout, stderr = my_process.communicate()
    except ValueError:
        stdout = b''
        stderr = b''
```

### Original Answer

Creating empty file objects for `stdout` and `stderr` could be a solution:

```
import io

try:
    my_process = Popen(someargs, stdin=None, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = my_process.communicate(timeout=10)
    my_process.wait()
except TimeoutExpired:
    my_process.kill()
    try:
        stdout, stderr = my_process.communicate()
    except ValueError:
        stdout = io.BytesIO()
        stderr = io.BytesIO()
```

Comment: Mike, won't that discard any information retrieved into those buffers during the "try" block?

Comment: you should use `stdout, stderr = b'', b''`, not `io.BytesIO()`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Added an improvement.

Comment: Is the `my_process.kill()` needed ?  The docs says: "If the timeout expires, the child process will be killed and waited for."

Comment: This is the help for `subprocess.run()`.  The help for `subprocessPopen()` says: "The child process is not killed if the timeout expires, so in order to cleanup properly a well-behaved application should kill the child process and finish communication."